# How to optimize a big 4D array containing "nan" values

Tags: python, arrays, bigdata, nan

I have an big array `data_neighbors` with `shape=(1, 3, 1000000, 112)` containing a lot of `nan` values.

```
array([[[[ 88.769226,  80.62714 ,  75.95856 ]],

    [[ 88.749695,  79.52362 ,  76.456604]],

    [[ 89.07196 ,  82.84393 ,  77.12067 ]],

    ...,

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]]],


   [[[ 88.769226,  80.62714 ,  75.95856 ]],

    [[ 88.749695,  79.52362 ,  76.456604]],

    [[ 89.07196 ,  82.84393 ,  77.12067 ]],

    ...,

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]]],


   [[[ 88.769226,  80.62714 ,  75.95856 ]],

    [[ 88.749695,  79.52362 ,  76.456604]],

    [[ 89.07196 ,  82.84393 ,  77.12067 ]],

    ...,

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]]],


   ...,


   [[[116.88446 , 119.25018 , 125.77301 ]],

    [[117.02118 , 118.58612 , 124.601135]],

    [[116.82587 , 118.84979 , 125.46051 ]],

    ...,

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]]],


   [[[117.02118 , 118.58612 , 124.601135]],

    [[116.98212 , 119.34784 , 125.89996 ]],

    [[116.91376 , 118.957214, 125.606995]],

    ...,

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]]],


   [[[117.099304, 119.45526 , 126.03668 ]],

    [[117.10907 , 118.81073 , 125.2359  ]],

    [[117.030945, 119.09393 , 125.79254 ]],

    ...,

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]],

    [[       nan,        nan,        nan]]]], dtype=float32)
```

How can I remove all `nan` values in this array to improve the memory use?
It's important to note that the number of nan values changes in the last dimension. For example: `data_neighbors[0,0,0].shape=3` and `data_neighbors[0,0,1].shape=112`. So, it will be impossible to result an array. Maybe lists in array?

EDIT :
The main objective of the script is to realize multi-point regridding. For each point of a grid A, I assign x values ​​of another grid B within a radius of x kilometers around the point. The x values ​​are determined by ind_regrid (1000000*112) a variable which contains for each index of A, the different points of B to integrate. Depending on the index of A, ind_regrid potentially contains nan values ​​in the 112 potential indices to regrid.

```
nc_conf       = Dataset(fic_regril, 'r')
print('-> Read regrid file '+str(fic_regril))
ind_regrid    = nc_conf.variables['inds_regrid'][:]
nc_conf.close()
masked_indices = np.ma.getmaskarray(ind_regrid)
data_neighbors = data[:,:,:,np.where(~masked_indices,ind_regrid,0)]
data_neighbors[masked_indices] = np.nan
data_neighbors_list.append(data_neighbors) #pt, regrid, param, time
```

Comment: The input and the expected output are not quite clear to me. You mention the shape of the `data_neighbors` array, but the array you've shown in your question appears to have been mangled when you pasted it to Stack Overflow. Do you mind [edit]ing your post to show a smaller example of your input that is representative of the actual input, and the expected output for that input? Can you also specify what you mean by "optimize"?

Comment: It might also help to tell us what calculations you are performing on the array. Numpy arrays can't have a ragged shape, so every element of an axis must contain the same number of elements. Changing it to a list of arrays will prohibit you from using numpy's vectorized operations on the dimension that was listified. If speed is more important than memory, it might be faster to just account for the nans instead of filtering them out

Comment: Thks @pho for your precision. I edited my post and precise the data_neighbors array. You're right, thanks to numpy's vectorized operations on array, the calculations are fast but data_neigbors uses 20Go of memory. I thought that by removing the nan values ​​it would avoid storing too many values. Maybe it exists other solutions to improve the memory use ?

Comment: Do you want rows with all `nan` value to be found or at least one `nan` is enough. Do want them to be removed to replaced by a value.